# Auto Comment Fill

Tags: feature-request

Hey everyone (sorry this is so long), I've recently discovered the amazing [auto comment add-on](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) that prevents one from having to retype comments constantly.

Could we please get a list of **recommended** (but not required) base Auto Fill that we could personalize a bit if we liked (or not)?  The default text is pretty... un-useful to the point that some of them don't actually address what it thinks it does.

I think it'd be great to have some standard that everyone can use without feeling like they're plagiarizing someone else.

I'm pretty sure that others are using this add-on and more may find better defaults helpful in the future.

If anyone's curious, here's what the defaults say now:

> **Answers to say Thanks**: *Welcome to Movies & TV! Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient privileges to upvote answers you like, which is the Movies & TV way of saying thank you.*

This one's probably fine.

> **Nothing but a URL (but not spam)**: *Welcome to Movies & TV! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.*

This one is ok, too... I guess... but who uses *whilst* anymore?

> **Request to the OP for more information**: *Welcome to Movies & TV! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, you will be able to post comments. For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.*

I think the title for this one is the problem, not necessarily the content of it.

> **OP using an answer for further information**: *Welcome to Movies & TV! Please use the Post answer button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.*

We really need a version of this for people who **aren't** the OP using answers to post comments.

> **OP adding a new question as an answer**: *Welcome to Movies & TV! If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button.*

I don't see this one having much use.

> **Another user adding a 'Me too!'**: *Welcome to Movies & TV! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. If you have sufficient reputation, you may upvote the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.*

I think this one happens but is pretty rare, too.

Ones that are missing:

- Requesting the OP provide more information in their question.
- Requesting an answer be explained more thoroughly (similar to the second one above).
- Explaining how a question is off topic (this could probably have a couple of varieties).

Others? I'm sure I'm missing some.